# how to change the name of index in array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    double[] numbers= new double [12];
    numbers[0]=0;
    numbers[1]=0;
    numbers[2]=0;
    numbers[3]=0;
    numbers[4]=0;
    numbers[5]=0;
    numbers[6]=0;
    numbers[7]=0;
    numbers[8]=0;
    numbers[9]=0;
    numbers[10]=0;
    numbers[11]=0;

    for (double i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
        numbers[(int)i]= in.nextDouble();
    }

    double max = numbers[0];
    double min = numbers[0];
    for (double i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
        if (numbers[(int)i] > max){ 
            max = numbers[(int)i];
        }
    }
    for (double i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){      
        if (numbers[(int)i] < min){
            min = numbers[(int)i];
        }
    }   
    double total = 0;
    double average = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        total += numbers[i];
    }

    average = total/12;

    System.out.println("The total rainfall for the year is "+ total + "mm with average "+ average + "mm");
    System.out.println("The months with the highest rainfall is " + max);
    System.out.println("The lowest amount rainfall for the year is " + min);
}
```

How do I change the index's name in array in java? For example, I want to convert `numbers[0]` to `numbers[january]`.

I'm trying to get the output of rainfall program. Instead of getting the max value like (123.45mm) I want to get its month as the output.

Thanks for help.

Comment: The name of the variable and the output of your program are two different things, though. I suspect your goal with this is... suspicious.

Comment: So you have an arrays with 12 items, each item is a double representing a certain month's rainfall. Item with index 0 is january and 11 is december?

Comment: Can you post a code sample?

Comment: Java isn't PHP. Arrays have indexes. Maps can have strings for keys, or, as suggested, you can define constants for the indexes. Your output is independent of the way Java arrays use indexes.

Comment: `for (double i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)` , you should better use int instead of double: `for (int i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)`

Answer (score 7):

You can use `java.util.Calendar` to avoid declaring a constant for each month

```
numbers[Calendar.JANUARY];
numbers[Calendar.FEBRUARY];
...
```

Comment: This is the most elegant solution IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

```
int january=0;
```

now you can use `numbers[january];`

Edit . 
A better solution is given above please refer that :)

Comment: The constants could be made `static final`

Comment: any simpler way instead of declaring all the months' name?

Comment: You could use the statics that are already built into the Calendar class. `Calendar.JANUARY` == `int (0)`

Comment: @azamembong There is really no simpler way, and it is not surprising. What you are trying to accomplish is incredibly useless. The output of your program and the name of your variables are not related. The compiler will rename all your variables anyway. You cannot extract the name of your variable.

Answer (score 0):

I would use and enum with proper field that is of the index value so you can reference the array index from the enum.  See Java doc for enum in the link below and look at the Planet enum as example. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

On a different note.  Would it make more sense to use the Map instead of array since you care both about the index as well as the value.  Your map would be like Map where the key is the month and the value is your measurement?

Answer (score 0):

An Array is certainly not the type of object you should use. you can consider a Collection instead, for example an `ArrayList`. (by the way, you then do not need to re-implement the `min` and the `max`)

Then you could search in your list the indexOf your min and the max value (there are eventually multiple results).

you could get the name of the month like following, assuming `i` is your index:

```
monthString = new java.text.DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[i];
```

So your code could ends with:

```
    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        list.add(numbers[i]);
    }
    String minMonth = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[list.indexOf(min)]; // note: only consider the first result
    String maxMonth = new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[list.indexOf(max)];

    System.out.println("The total rainfall for the year is " + total + "mm with average " + average + " mm");
    System.out.println("The months with the highest rainfall is " + maxMonth);
    System.out.println("The lowest amount rainfall for the year is " + minMonth);
```

and you'll get an output like:

> The total rainfall for the year is 13100.4mm with average 1091.7 mm
>   The months with the highest rainfall is Juli
>   The lowest amount rainfall for the year is August